# ¿Cómo uso un tipo de variable de una clase mia, para poderla usar en un metodo?

Tags: java, eclipse, método

Hola a todos es primera vez que formulo una pregunta en este foro, seré conciso, necesito usar esta clase fecha que me han dado, para ello me piden crear un método estático con esta clase que por parámetro reciba 2 objetos de la clase fecha y me retorne la cantidad de días entre estos dos.

```
   public class Fecha{

    private int anio;
        private int mes;
        private int dia;


    public Fecha(int anio, int mes, int dia) {
        super();
        this.anio = anio;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public int getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    public int getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fecha [anio=" + anio + ", mes=" + mes + ", dia=" + dia + "]";

}
```

}

lo primero en que yo pensé fue hacer una resta de estos y retornar el resultado pero no se como pasarlo al código muchas gracias. Esto es lo que he echo:

```
public static int diasEntre(Fecha a, Fecha b) {

    int diasEntre = Math.abs(a)-Math.abs(b);

    return diasEntre;

}
```

Comment: Tu ultimo codigo esta mal porque restas los dos objetos

Comment: ¿Que es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: exacto denifer lo se que esta mal, lo que quiero hacer es encontrar los dias cuando le pase por parametro dos objetos de tipo fecha, ¿cómo lo logro?, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Tenes que crear una funcion (justamente esa) que calcule las diferencias. Obviamente esto es un ejercicio, asi que no se cual metodo te dejaran usar para calcular eso. podrias explicar un poco mas que podes y no podes hacer???

Comment: @gbianchi exacto necesito una función que me calcule los dias entre esos 2 objetos fecha que le paso por parametro, pero no logro saber como hacerlo, debido a que ese metodo que hice no sirve porque me estoy restando 2 objetos

Comment: y si contas los dias desde el que sea el año menor hasta el que tenga el mayor? no es optimo, pero me parece que la idea es que aprendas un algoritmo. Si no, el objeto Date de Java sabe como calcular la diferencia.

Comment: Exacto tienes dos opciones: crear un algoritmo que convierta la fecha en un entero(numero de dias) y restarlo y volver a convertirlo o usar la clase Date para lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

Espero esto pueda ayudarte:

```
 public static int diasEntre(Fecha a, Fecha b) {
        //Inicializamos las clases calendar
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(a.getAnio(),a.getMes(), a.getDia());
        Calendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar(b.getAnio(),b.getMes(), b.getDia());

        //Calculamos la diferencia en milisegundos entre los días
        long diferenciaMills = calendar.getTime().getTime() - calendar2.getTime().getTime();
        //Si la diferencia está en negativo la pasamos a positivo
        if (diferenciaMills < 0) {
            diferenciaMills *= -1;
        }
        //Creamos otra clase Calendar iniciandola con el valor de la diferencia entre las fechas
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(diferenciaMills);

        //Retornamos la anterior clase calendar como días
        return c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    }
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me ayudo mucho y si algo asi estaba buscando, Gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), para convertirlo a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) para después de cada fecha obtener los milisegundos con **getTime()** (regresa el número de milisegundos desde  Enero 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT del objeto [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)), y simplemente se hace la resta para después convertirlo a días con la siguiente formula **(diferencia en milisegundos) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)**:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fecha fecha1 = new Fecha(2018,10,20);
        Fecha fecha2 = new Fecha(2018,10,25);
        long resultado = Test.restaFechas(fecha1,fecha2);
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }

    public static long restaFechas(Fecha fecha1, Fecha fecha2 ){
        Date d1= null;
        Date d2= null;
        long diff = 0;
        try {
            d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(fecha1.getAnio()+"-"+fecha1.getMes()+"-"+fecha1.getDia());
            d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(fecha2.getAnio()+"-"+fecha2.getMes()+"-"+fecha2.getDia());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        System.out.println("Difference between  " + d1 + " and "+ d2+" is "
            + (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + " days.");
        return (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }
}


class Fecha{

    private int anio;
        private int mes;
        private int dia;


    public Fecha(int anio, int mes, int dia) {
        super();
        this.anio = anio;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public int getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    public int getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fecha [anio=" + anio + ", mes=" + mes + ", dia=" + dia + "]";

    }
}
```

Este es el resultado que arroja con valores **fecha1**: día: 20, mes: 10 y año: 2018 y **fecha2**: día: 25, mes: 10 y año: 2018:

Diferencia entre fechas:Sat Oct 20 00:00:00 CDT 2018 and Thu Oct 25 00:00:00 CDT 2018 is 5 days.

5

Comment: Gracias amigo me ayudo mucho y si algo asi estaba buscando, Gracias nuevamente